# Sorting python whoosh results

Tags: python, whoosh

I have this fragment of code:

```
from whoosh import index, qparser

def find(text, indexDir, _doc_schema):
    parser = qparser.QueryParser("content", schema=_doc_schema, termclass=FuzzyTerm)
    query = parser.parse(text)
    index = index.open_dir(indexDir)
    with index.searcher() as searcher:
        for res in searcher.search(query, limit=limit, terms=True):
             result = {
                   "classname": res["classname"],
                   "code": res["code"],
             }
             if highlights:
                  result["text"] = res.highlights("content")
             print "Res ", result['text']
             print "Matched terms ", res.matched_terms()
             yield result
```

Is there a way to sort my matched_terms by correlation level  while searching? So if I am looking for 'aaa', I want terms 'aaa' to come first, but they may come after 'aab' results.

Comment: you want to sort results or only terms?

Comment: `print "Matched terms ", sorted(res.matched_terms())`

Comment: bigOTHER, yes, I want to sort results, my bad again.

Comment: Piter Wood, sorted() would not work, because res.matched_terms() return only all terms of 1 res and I need to compare terms of all my res.

Comment: Have you read about [sorting in Whoosh](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/sorting.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you yield the matched terms along with the result, you can build a dictionary of terms to results:

```
yield result, res.matched_terms()
```

Then build the dictionary:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for result, terms in find(text, indexDir, _doc_schema):
...     for term in terms:
...         d.setdefault(term, []).append(result)
```

You can then iterate through the dictionary in order:

```
>>> for term in sorted(d.keys()):
...     print key, result['classname'], result['code']
```